# I am getting a redux logger error when I try to upload an ecommerce app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, moltin, redux-logger

I am trying to build an e-commerce store app in React with Moltin JS. Everytime I try to upload it to Heroku, I get a blank page or an error.  The error said that it could not resolve "redux-logger".  I have tried re-downloading redux logger and also npm install.  I still get the same error message. I've also tried NPM update. It works fine when I launch it from my VS Code.
[github docs](https://github.com/VintageVoodoo13/mindysstore.git)
[Heroku Page](https://limitless-meadow-27226.herokuapp.com/)

```html
// import the ability to modify browser history within our router
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

// import our logger for redux
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

// import a library to handle async with redux
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// import the redux parts needed to start our store
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

// import the middleware for using react router with redux
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';

// import the already combined reducers for redux to use
import rootReducer from './ducks';

// import moltin API wrapper for use with Redux
import * as api from './moltin';

// create and export history for router
export const history = createHistory();

// combine the middlewares we're using into a constant so that it can be used by our store
const middleware = [thunk.withExtraArgument(api), routerMiddleware(history)];

// declare any enhancers here
const enhancers = [];

// use Redux devtools if available in development
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension;

  if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
    enhancers.push(devToolsExtension());
  }

  middleware.push(createLogger());
}

// compose our middleware
const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers);

// create our redux store using our reducers and our middleware, and export it for use in index.js
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancers);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is that Heroku installs only production dependencies on deployment by default, so the ones that are listed under `dependencies` key of you `package.json` by running `npm install --production`.

Move dependencies that are crucial to your app running - like redux-logger - from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` and that should solve your problem.

`devDependencies` are meant for things that support you in development, but are not required for the production copy of your app to run, like testing modules, for example.

Comment: P.S. I smashed my head on the table for quite some time the first time i encountered this problem with Heroku. Their node support docs are not super straightforward about it and the error message is vague.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This was driving me crazy.

Comment: I'd greatly appreciate if you mark it as the right answer, if it helped.